# Using on screen keyboard in Excel brings up VBA Editor window (bug?)

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2013 (on Surface Pro 2, Win 8.1)
It seems weird but every time I click on a button to bring up on screen keyboard (to add data to cells, textboxes, etc.) it also opens VBA Editor window (which is not desirable). Anyone knows how to switch it off? (So keyboard will open but not VBA Editor).

Many thanks

Comment: this Q is better suited for [SU]

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. If the keyboard is "attached to the screen"  (small icon in the upper right corner) then opening the keyboard will automatically open VBA Editor window (at least in my case). Clicking the icon and "detaching" the keyboard helps and the VBA Editor windows doesn't appear anymore :)